# Wordpress: How to set default (active) theme via script

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to assign the "active" theme via script. Anyone know the API call needed to do this? Also, how do I retrieve the current theme via script (PHP)?

Comment: Why don't you just look at the `wp_options` table in the database and set it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update `current_theme` option:

```
update_option('current_theme', '[theme name]');
```

To get the theme's name use:

```
$themes = get_themes();
```

Answer (score 2):

In current Wordpress version 3.4.2 you need to update 3 options to switch to another theme(minihyper - in my case)

```
update_option('template', 'minihyper');
update_option('stylesheet', 'minihyper');
update_option('current_theme', 'Mini Hyper');
```

The first two options are key, the third really does nothing except maybe you can use this option somewhere in code to display current theme name.

**Update:**

Here is a true way:

```
<?php switch_theme( $template, $stylesheet ) ?>
```

Example with minihyper:

```
<?php switch_theme( 'minihyper', 'minihyper' ) ?>
```